# How can I achieve this in Android TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, textview

I am displaying some numbers in android textview, I want to make the look of the numbers like the pictures shown below. 
Is there a way to add background image for every character in the textview or is there some other way to achieve this?

I searched for answers on google and SO but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="1234567890"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to create a custom view for this.  TextView won't cut it.

Answer (score 2):

Download a font like this and tell the textview to use it.
http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-images-flip-board-letters-numbers-image21493569

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/my_font.ttf"); 
tvTotal.setTypeface(type);
```